# Edge contractions of a graph but only along maximum cliques.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Consider the following operation to an undirected graph: one is allowed to take any maximum clique and replace the clique with a single vertex which is attached to every single vertex which has an edge into the clique. Essentially then one is allowed to do a bunch of simultaneous edge contractions but only if they all form a maximum clique. One can then talk about what graphs can be formed from other graphs this way. Note that a graph A can be formed from a graph B this way, then A is a minor of B, but the converse does not hold.

Is there a term in the literature for this graph relationship? I'm not about 80% certain I've seen this before but I don't recall the name or where I've previously seen it.

Comment: Does quotient graph fit your needs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_graph

Comment: @RandyMarsh A quotient graph will not in general be the same thing.  A quotient graph is a bit more broad since it allows one to merge a group that is not a maximum clique.